# Why can't Elves create more Rings?

Tags: tolkiens-legendarium, the-lord-of-the-rings

I have a question concerning the creation of rings in *the Lord of the Rings*. It's, at least, hinted that the reason the Elves depart for Valinor after the demise of Sauron is because their Rings lose their power of preservation, hence the enchantments on Lothlorien would eventually wane, making it less like Valinor. But why can't they create more? Lets look at the Facts:

Fact 1 : We know that Celebrimbor is the only Elf that can forge the rings since Sauron under the guise of Annatar taught him how to. We also know that Celebrimbor was killed by Sauron before he could reveal this knowledge. However, Elves can't truly die until the end of the world and are lingering about in Valinor and I am sure that's where Celebrimbor is.

Fact 2: We know that Elves can go to Valinor and come back to Middle-earth since the Noldor have done precisely this.

So my question is, Why can't an Elf go to Valinor, learn the secret of forging rings from Celebrimbor, come back to Middle-earth and forge new ones?

Some are suggesting this question is a duplicate but I don't see how. I am suggesting a possibility where an opportunity was indeed present. Answers such as the elves fearing the past does not seem too convincing to me, after all it was a Maiar that got corrupted not the ring wearing elves. Why would they doubt themselves?

Comment: The question you pose is answered in the duplicates accepted answer, if the answers are insufficient you should use a bounty to ask for a better answer, or to leave a comment. Asking a duplicate question is not ok. If your question instead focused on the ability for an Elf to go to the Halls of Mandos and discuss things with Celebrimbor, that would no longer be a duplicate.

Comment: @Edlothiad I thought the question concerning the ability of an elf to meet celebrimbor in halls of Mandos is subsumed by the present one since an answer to this potentially answers the former as well.

Comment: If all they want to do with the rings is make Middle Earth feel more like Valinor, why not just stay in Valinor?

Comment: No. The ability of an elf to go to the halls is _quite_ different to why they can't or won't make more rings

Comment: I think the esssential part of this question is whether or not the elves could have gone to Valinor and back had they wanted to do so.  I have the impression they couldn't have, but no knowledge to back it up.

Comment: @HarryJohnston they couldn't have, but that's not what the question asks. The question asks why elves can't make more rings, with that as a possible way to make more rings. The dupe target effectively says "They wouldn't go to valinor and back because of these reasons"

Comment: @Edlothiad, except that the dupe is talking about before Sauron's fall and this question is asking about afterwards; the circumstances are different, so the existing answer doesn't really fully address this question IMO.  Anyway, my suggestion to the OP is that if this question were edited - or reposted - asking *just* whether the elves could have gone to Valinor and back after Sauron's fall to learn how to forge new rings, it wouldn't be a duplicate.  Or, at least, not that *particular* duplicate. :-)

Comment: @HarryJohnston no it isn't, it's talking about both. That was my suggestion as well, the advice wasn't taken.

Comment: Originally read this as *"why can't ELVIS create more rings?"*  Realized my error soon enough, but still had fun mentally substituting "Elvis" for "elves" throughout the question.

Comment: @Edlothiad *The ability of an elf to go to the Halls is quite different to the they can't or won't make more rings* - well, the Halls of Mandos is where Celebrimbor's spirit hangs out. So if an ordinary meat-bodied elf cannot go there, and Celebrimbor cannot or would not leave, then it means they can't learn how to make the rings. Which means they aren't able to make more rings. And not being able to make more rings relates pretty directly to why they won't make more rings.

Comment: @MishaRosnach I see your point. However, the ability for an elf to go there is a separate question to "Why can't or won't they make more rings". While it would certainly aid the latter, the former and latter are entirely separate. A "resurrected" Elf could well have liaised with Celebrimbor and learnt the ring lore, however, the dupe target highlights why they wouldn't have made more rings.